# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null after i try to do it again

Tags: javascript, html

I have read multiple answers given to my problem but none made any change.
My problem is that when I press the "Reset" button it resets it doesn't show me all the info it should. For some reason, it can't find the id of the line I want to change.

So in short: It gives errors after I press the "Reset button".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name1">Name1</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name2">Name2</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name3">Name3</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name4">Name4</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name5">Name5</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name6">Name6</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name7">Name7</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name8">Name8</button>
    <button onclick="Randomize()">Randomize</button>
    <button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
    <p id="Spelers">Players: <span id="RandomNames"></span></p>
    <p id="TotalPlayers">Total Players: <span id="TotalMembers">0</span></p>
    <p>Team 1: <span id="TeamOne"></span></p>
    <p>Team 2: <span id="TeamTwo"></span></p>

   <script>
        var Names = [];
        var Team1 = [];
        var Team2 = [];

        function SetName(NameClicked) {
            if(!(Names.includes(NameClicked))) {
                Names.push(NameClicked);
            } else {
                var DeleteNamePos = Names.indexOf(NameClicked);
                Names.splice(DeleteNamePos, 1); 
            }
            document.getElementById("RandomNames").innerHTML = Names;
            document.getElementById("TotalMembers").innerHTML = Names.length;
        }

        function Randomize() {
            var i = 1;
            while(i <= Names.length)   {
                var RandomNameSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
                Team1.push(Names[RandomNameSelect]);
                Names.splice(RandomNameSelect, 1);

                var RandomNameSelect2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
                Team2.push(Names[RandomNameSelect2]);
                Names.splice(RandomNameSelect2, 1);
            }
            document.getElementById("Spelers").innerHTML = "Teams are: ";
            document.getElementById("TotalPlayers").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("TeamOne").innerHTML = Team1;
            document.getElementById("TeamTwo").innerHTML = Team2;
        }

        function Reset() {
            Names = [];
            Team1 = [];
            Team2 = [];
            document.getElementById("TotalPlayers").innerHTML = "Total players: ";
            document.getElementById("Spelers").innerHTML = "Players: ";
            document.getElementById("TeamOne").innerHTML = Team1;
            document.getElementById("TeamTwo").innerHTML = Team2;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Also a link for a code snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/u2wt9qpe/

Comment: because you remove the element... you should be resetting `<span id="TotalMembers">0</span>`, not resetting the innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resetting the values through `Reset()` function, you have removed the inner elements like `RandomNames` and `TotalMembers`. As a workaround, you can add those two elements again when resetting.

```js
var Names = [];
        var Team1 = [];
        var Team2 = [];

        function SetName(NameClicked) {
            if(!(Names.includes(NameClicked))) {
                Names.push(NameClicked);
            } else {
                var DeleteNamePos = Names.indexOf(NameClicked);
                Names.splice(DeleteNamePos, 1); 
            }
            document.getElementById("RandomNames").innerHTML = Names;
            document.getElementById("TotalMembers").innerHTML = Names.length;
        }

        function Randomize() {
            var i = 1;
            while(i <= Names.length)   {
                var RandomNameSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
                Team1.push(Names[RandomNameSelect]);
                Names.splice(RandomNameSelect, 1);

                var RandomNameSelect2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
                Team2.push(Names[RandomNameSelect2]);
                Names.splice(RandomNameSelect2, 1);
            }
            document.getElementById("Spelers").innerHTML = "Teams are: ";
            document.getElementById("TotalPlayers").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("TeamOne").innerHTML = Team1;
            document.getElementById("TeamTwo").innerHTML = Team2;
        }

        function Reset() {
            Names = [];
            Team1 = [];
            Team2 = [];
            document.getElementById("TotalPlayers").innerHTML = 'Total Players: <span id="TotalMembers">0</span>';
            document.getElementById("Spelers").innerHTML = 'Players: <span id="RandomNames"></span>';
            document.getElementById("TeamOne").innerHTML = Team1;
            document.getElementById("TeamTwo").innerHTML = Team2;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name1">Name1</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name2">Name2</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name3">Name3</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name4">Name4</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name5">Name5</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name6">Name6</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name7">Name7</button>
    <button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name8">Name8</button>
    <button onclick="Randomize()">Randomize</button>
    <button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
    <p id="Spelers">Players: <span id="RandomNames"></span></p>
    <p id="TotalPlayers">Total Players: <span id="TotalMembers">0</span></p>
    <p>Team 1: <span id="TeamOne"></span></p>
    <p>Team 2: <span id="TeamTwo"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

On `Reset()` function, you have set html data to `TotalPlayers` and `Spelers` selectors using `innerHTML`.
So the inner span tags, `TotalMembers`, and `RandomNames` selectors are removed.

To reset the data, it is needed to make `TotalMembers` and `RandomNames` selectors empty as follows.

```js
var Names = [];
var Team1 = [];
var Team2 = [];

function SetName(NameClicked) {
  if (!(Names.includes(NameClicked))) {
    Names.push(NameClicked);
  } else {
    var DeleteNamePos = Names.indexOf(NameClicked);
    Names.splice(DeleteNamePos, 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("RandomNames").innerHTML = Names;
  document.getElementById("TotalMembers").innerHTML = Names.length;
}

function Randomize() {
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= Names.length) {
    var RandomNameSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
    Team1.push(Names[RandomNameSelect]);
    Names.splice(RandomNameSelect, 1);

    var RandomNameSelect2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
    Team2.push(Names[RandomNameSelect2]);
    Names.splice(RandomNameSelect2, 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("Spelers").innerHTML = "Teams are: ";
  document.getElementById("TotalMembers").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("TeamOne").innerHTML = Team1;
  document.getElementById("TeamTwo").innerHTML = Team2;
}

function Reset() {
  Names = [];
  Team1 = [];
  Team2 = [];
  document.getElementById("TotalMembers").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("RandomNames").innerText = "";
  document.getElementById("TeamOne").innerText = Team1;
  document.getElementById("TeamTwo").innerText = Team2;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name1">Name1</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name2">Name2</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name3">Name3</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name4">Name4</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name5">Name5</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name6">Name6</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name7">Name7</button>
<button onclick="SetName(this.id)" id=" Name8">Name8</button>
<button onclick="Randomize()">Randomize</button>
<button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
<p id="Spelers">Players: <span id="RandomNames"></span></p>
<p id="TotalPlayers">Total Players: <span id="TotalMembers">0</span></p>
<p>Team 1: <span id="TeamOne"></span></p>
<p>Team 2: <span id="TeamTwo"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initially set up the DOM, you have  Players:

.   Notice that Element with ID=RandomNames is a child of the element with ID="Spelers".   When you execute either the reset() or the randomize(),  this line   document.getElementById("Spelers").innerHTML = "Teams are: "; <--- will remove the child element with ID="RandomNames" as it replaces everything.   This will no longer be available on the DOM the next time you call SetName().   You could add code to replace this element after resetting.